Anexar PDF con c#
Buenos dias gente ando necesitando poder anexar un pdf dentro de otro pero no le encuentro una solucion todavia. Aca les mando el codigo de lo que estoy realizando o si hay otra alternativa. Mi idea era la siguiente que con openfile_Dialog busque el pdf suelto una vez que lo toma buscar el pdf donde se tiene que amoldar este pdf suelto y que lo genere
        private void MixPDFS()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor, selecciona ambos archivos antes de mezclar.");
                return;
            }

            string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath2);
            string outputFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath2) + ".pdf";
            string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, outputFileName);

            try
            {
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    Document document = new Document();
                    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
                    document.Open();

                    List<string> fileNames = new List<string> { filePath1, filePath2 };

                    foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
                    {
                        PdfReader reader = null;
                        try
                        {
                            reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
                            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                            {
                                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            // Asegúrate de cerrar el PdfReader incluso si ocurre una excepción
                            if (reader != null)
                            {
                                reader.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    document.Close();
                }

                MessageBox.Show($"Los archivos han sido mezclados y guardados como {outputFilePath}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error al mezclar los archivos PDF: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


Te recomiendo utilizar librerías de terceros.
Aquí hay un ejemplo utilizando iTextSharp (este código es de una versión antigua, quizá necesite ser actualizado).
    public static void MergePdf(Stream outputPdfStream, IEnumerable<string> pdfFilePaths)
    {
        using (var document = new Document())
        using (var pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(document, outputPdfStream))
        {
            pdfCopy.CloseStream = false;
            try
            {
                document. Open();
                foreach (var pdfFilePath in pdfFilePaths)
                {
                    using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
                    {
                        pdfCopy.AddDocument(pdfReader);
                        pdfReader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                document?. Close();
            }
        }
    }

El constructor de PdfReader tiene muchas sobrecargas. Es posible reemplazar el parametro de tipo IEnumerable<string> con IEnumerable<Stream> y debería funcionar también. Nótese que el método no cierra el OutputStream eso es responsabilidad del creador del stream.
Alternativamente podría utilizar PDFSharp
using (PdfDocument one = PdfReader.Open("file1.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
using (PdfDocument two = PdfReader.Open("file2.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
using (PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument())
{                
    CopyPages(one, outPdf);
    CopyPages(two, outPdf);

    outPdf.Save("file1and2.pdf");
}

void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
    {
        to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
    }
}

